# Issue while resizing Azure Managed data disks

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk, mbr

**Below are my configurations:**

Azure VM is in West Europe Region

**NOTE** : It is a Generation 1 VM

Current size: Standard_D2_v2_Promo

**Actual Requirement:** Our requirement is to have a one 4TB disk instead of 2*2 TB disks .

**Disks**:
[image]

In the above image I tried to increase disk4 from 2TB --> 4TB by stopping VM.

**Issue:** After I Increased the disk , I tried to extend the disk in the servers itself after RDP , but cannot expand it as the disk format is MBR. I think the limit to MBR is 2TB and not more ?

Are there any restrictions for this VM Size "Standard_D2_v2_Promo" that all my disks are "MBR" and not GPT ?

[image]

**Future Planning:**

Also now I am looking to upgrade the VM size from "Standard_D2_v2_Promo" to either "DS2_V2" or "DS3_V3"

[image]

If I upgrade to DS2_V2 or DS3_V3 will I be able to use GPT disks or still I will be having only MBR disks of 2 TB maximum size.

Please advice . Thanks

Comment: As you said with MBR you are limited to 2 TBs.

Answer (score 1):

You need Generation 2 VM for GPT.

Generation 1 images can only use GPT partitioning on data disks, not OS disks. OS disks must use the MBR partition style.

Generation 2 images can use GPT partitioning on the OS disk as well as the data disks. Gen2 VMs support up to a 4 TiB OS disk. Azure supports up to 32 TiB for managed data disks.

---

Sources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/generation-2 (list of gen2 VMs)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/faq-for-disks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks

Comment: My VM is "VM generation V1". Can you please help me understand it , you mentioned "Generation 1 images can only use GPT partitioning on data disks" , in my context they are data disks as seen in the image of Disks, still why I can't expand !

Comment: @Learning_Learning, check the expand disks documentation. It states " MBR limits the usable size to 2 TiB. If you need more than 2 TiB, create and attach data disks and use them for data storage. If you need to store data on the OS disk and require the additional space, convert it to GUID Partition Table (GPT)." I think if you upgrade to Gen2 VM it would make everything easier for you.

Comment: Since there is limitation to expand from 2 TB for your current vm, maybe you can attach a disk instead of expanding. https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal

Comment: Yeah since I already have 8 data disks attached for this VM Size currently has a limitation. I need to resize VM first to DS2_V2 or DS3_V3 and then add a new disk. is what I am thinking

Comment: @Learning_Learning, I hope it resolves your issues then :)